# Preserving permission on archive failed using tar

Tags: linux, permissions, tar, archive

I'm trying to make archive of /var/log/messages with preserving permissions, but when I look for the permission of my archive file I found it different.

[root@nn tmp]# tar -cvpf new.tar /var/log/messages

tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
/var/log/messages

[root@nn tmp]# ls -l /var/log/messages

-rw-------. 1 root root 3377818 Jun  8 11:43 /var/log/messages

[root@nn tmp]# ls -l new.tar

-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3389440 Jun  8 11:44 new.tar

see permission on archive is totally different as compare to the original one.

Answer (score 0):

The `-p` ≡ `--preserve-permissions` ≡ `--same-permissions` flag is about permissions of files stored in the archive, not about the archive file itself.

Use `umask 0077` to create new files without any permissions for user other than the owner.